# Unspecified error running BPT test from ALM

Tags: hp-uft, hp-alm

I have HP UFT 12.01 installed and using BPT to write GUI automation scripts and then integrate them into ALM 12.53. UFT can connect to ALM using the connection tool in it, but when inside ALM and trying to run a test using the business components I wrote, it gives an error message "unidentified error". And then when trying to open the component from inside ALM using the "Launch HP UFT", but get the message suggesting that UFT is not installed.
I've tried reinstalling both ALM client and UFT and all related components but still get the issue.
I've been through many support boards but nothing can resolve the issue.

I need some help.

[image: error when trying to open uft from alm]

[image: error when running test with components]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

- ALM connectivity tool is installed
- ALM and UFT are on the same PC
- UFT installation setting checked to allow other software to execute tests

Please list all of the locally installed software versions relating to UFT, ALM and their add-ons.